# Как сделать так, чтобы частицы запускались при нажатии на кнопкуUI?

Tags: unity3d

Хочу сделать так, чтобы частицы появлялись, когда игрок нажимает на кнопку в интерфейсе(не на клавиатуре)?

Comment: Какой интерфейс ты используешь, UI или устаревший GUI? Что именно ты уже пробовал? Что не получилось? Пока что вопрос и слишком размытый и не совсем соответствует качеству. Пожалуста, ознакомься с правилами по задаванию вопросов:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @FixiDens 1. ресурс не гарантирует получение ответа. Но если уж ответ на вопрос тебе очень важен, ты можешь заработать балы (хорошими ответами, конечно же) а потом выставить приз за ответ на свой вопрос и тогда с большей вероятностью кто-то постарается ответить. 2. Что бы ресурс смог ответить на твой вопрос нужно как минимум хорошо оформить вопрос. 3. Это не дохлый ресурс, это кое-кто не умеет им пользоваться. Но если уж есть мнение что он дохлый, можно перетий на enSO. :) Там ответы дают быстрее. Правда и минусов быстрее наставляют.

Comment: сделай префаб частиц > при нажатии на кнопку создавай на позиции курсора

Answer (score 1):

```
//Добавьте в кнопку Button в OnClick, далее добавить префаб в prefab в инспекторе
    public void SpawnParticl(GameObject prefab)
    {
        var particl = Instantiate(prefab);
        //Выставьте  позицию в  new Vector3(0,0,0) или присвойте что то другое
        prefab.transform.position = new Vector3(0,0,0); 
    }
```